# Delete samples from genlight/genind object in adegenet R package

Tags: r

I just analyzed my data using adegenet and i realize I have to delete some samples. Is there a way of deleting samples by name? i tried this but this doesnt work

> `Dat1<-dat@ind.names[-c("sampleId10")]`

Answer (score 2):

```
Dat1 <- dat[indNames(dat) != "sampleId10"]
```

where 'dat' is the original genind object, and Dat1 is the modified genind object with sampleId10 removed.